# Proof by induction: For all $n \geq 1$; $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots +(-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n} \leq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

Proof by induction: For all $n \geq 1$; $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots +(-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n} \leq 1$

This is what I have so far:

Base case: for $n = 1$

$(-1)^{1+1} \cdot \frac{1}{1} \leq 1$

$(-1)^2 \leq 1$

$1 \leq 1$

This holds true.

Inductive step: for $n = k$

Assume $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots + (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k} \leq 1$ is true.

We want to show for $K=1$

$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots + (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k} - (-1)^{k+2} \cdot \frac{1}{K+1} \leq 1$

$(-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k} - (-1)^{k+2} \cdot \frac{1}{K+1} \leq 1$

By doing some algebra I get this:

$-\dfrac{(-1)^k + (-1)^k k + (-1)^K k)}{k(1 + k)} \leq 1$

`I am lost here, not sure if this says anything.` Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can right click on a mathematical formula to see the LaTeX commands I used to typeset the formula.  Also, please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202112/proving-bounds-of-a-harmonic-series

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** rewrite the sum as
$$
1-\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)-\left(\frac14-\frac15\right)-\left(\frac16-\frac17\right)-\dots
$$

Comment: Some times you want to use induction not on $n$, but on $2n$, $2n+1$, or something else like that, i.e. let one induction step cover more than one single case.

Comment: Indeed. I figured that if we showed that the sum was less than $1$ after adding each positive term, we wouldn't need to worry about the sum after adding the negative ones.

Comment: Got it thank you @robjohn