# Show
$\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p}<1$
for all positive number $p$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Show that
$$\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p}<1$$
for all positive number $p$.
And the given hint is that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$ is convex for $x>0$.

I can find the upper bound 1, but have no
ideas for its lower bound. How can I exploit the convexity of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^p}$?

Comment: Did you mean for $p > 1$ ? $\eta(0) = 1/2$ but for $p$ close to $0$, showing $\eta'(p) > 0$ is not so obvious

Comment: @reuns: a probabilistic interpretation makes it pretty obvious.

Comment: I have retracted my closing vote. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202112/proving-bounds-of-a-harmonic-series proves it only for $p > 1$, not for any positive $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the given hint that $f(x) = \frac {1}{x^p}$ is (strictly) convex we have
$$
 \frac{1}{(2j)^p} < \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{(2j-1)^p} + \frac{1}{(2j+1)^p} \right) \, .
$$

So for odd $N \ge 3$
$$
 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} - \frac{1}{4^p} + \frac{1}{5^p} - \frac{1}{6^p} + \frac{1}{7^p}- \ldots -\frac{1}{(N-1)^p} + \frac{1}{N^p} \\
> 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} - \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{3^p} +\frac{1}{5^p} \right) + \frac{1}{5^p}
- \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{5^p}+\frac{1}{7^p} \right) + \frac{1}{7^p}
- \ldots \\- \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{(N-2)^p}+\frac{1}{N^p} \right)  + \frac{1}{N^p} \\
= 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{3^p}+ \frac{1}{N^p} \right)
$$

Or – if you prefer it more formally – with $N=2k+1$:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p} = 
 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} + \sum_{j=2}^{k} \left( - \frac{1}{(2j)^p} + \frac{1}{(2j+1)^p} \right) \\
 > 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac{1}{3^p} +  \sum_{j=2}^{k} \frac 12 \left( - \frac{1}{(2j-1)^p} + \frac{1}{(2j+1)^p} \right) \\
 = 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{3^p}+ \frac{1}{N^p} \right)
$$
(telescoping sum).

It follows that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p} \ge 1 - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac 12 \frac{1}{3^p} = \frac 12 + \left( \frac 12 \frac{1}{1^p} - \frac{1}{2^p} + \frac 12 \frac{1}{3^p}\right) > \frac 12
$$
using the convexity once again.

Comment: So you did not need the inequality you observed from the convexity while writing it "more formally"?

Comment: @VIVID: It is used at $\left( - \frac{1}{(2j)^p} + \frac{1}{(2j+1)^p} \right) >  \frac 12 \left( - \frac{1}{(2j-1)^p} + \frac{1}{(2j+1)^p} \right)$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the rearrangement here, sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By the inverse Laplace transform, for any $p>0$,
$$ \eta(p)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^p}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{p-1}e^{-s}}{\Gamma(p)}\cdot\frac{ds}{1+e^{-s}}=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+\exp(-X)}\right] \tag{A}$$
where $X$ is a random variable with a [$\Gamma(p,1)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).
Given the RHS of $(A)$, the inequality $\frac{1}{2}<\eta(p)<1$ is trivial.